# How to know when a Drupal Node is new

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-5

I want to do a list of new nodes. I went to the code for the path "admin/content/node" which has a similar list, and I found it considers as "new" when the node timestamp is relatively close to the current date.

I'm afraid I can not trust on this method, because the timestamp is taken from the "changed" node field, and it gets updated everytime the node is updated (i.e: when an user "likes" a node)

Is there other reliable method to determine when a node is NEW? (I'm using Drupal5)

thanks

Comment: try here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$node->created - assuming that is existed in D5